# proper way to handle missing IPv6 connectivity

Tags: networking, go

I'm currently looking for a way to properly handle missing IPv6 connectivity.

The use case is, that i resolve a DNS record which might contain `AAAA` records and connect to each of the resolved IPs. Now the system running that code might not have IPv6 connectivity.

So i'm looking for the proper way to handle this and ignore these records, but only if the host can't connect anyway.

My current approach is:

```
if ip.To4() == nil && err.(*net.OpError).Err.(*os.SyscallError).Err == syscall.EHOSTUNREACH {
    log.Info("ignoring unreachable IPv6 address")
    continue
}
```

But i'm not sure, if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a `net.Dialer` with `DualStack` set to `true` and just `Dial()` using a name and let the library handle the "happy eyeballs" for you.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not an option here, as i want to connect to every host specified (monitoring check), so i'm just looking for the best way to filter out ipv6 records if there's no ipv6 connectivity